# Package Java classes under WEB-INF folder in WAR file

Tags: java, ant, war

I am using the following to package war file in ANT script

```
<target name="war" depends="compile">
    <war destfile="${deploy.dir}/vms_war.war" webxml="${web.dir}/WEB-INF/web.xml">
      <fileset dir="${classes.dir}">
        <include name="**/*.class"/>
        <exclude name="test/**/*.class"/>
      </fileset>
       <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
       <include name="**/*.xml"/>
      </fileset>
      <fileset dir="${web.dir}">
        <include name="**/*.jspx"/>
        <include name="**/*.jsp"/>
        <include name="**/*.html"/>                        
        <include name="WEB-INF/*.xml"/>
        <include name="WEB-INF/lib/*.*"/>
        <exclude name="**/web.xml"/>
      </fileset>
    </war>
  </target>
```

When war is packaged, the structure is as follows

```
--WEB-INF
  lib 
  web.xml
  faces-config.xml
--mypackageappname
     app
     test
     Login.class
     Authenticate.class
     ....
```

What I would like to achieve is when `war` is packaged, I would want to put java classes to be under `WEB-INF` folder along with `lib` folder.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [WAR Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/war.html) documentation says (in part) *The nested `classes` element specifies a FileSet. All files included in this fileset will end up in the WEB-INF/classes directory of the war file.* I think you wanted something like

```
<war destfile="${deploy.dir}/vms_war.war" webxml="${web.dir}/WEB-INF/web.xml">
  <classes dir="${classes.dir}" />
  <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
    <include name="**/*.xml"/>
  </fileset>
  <fileset dir="${web.dir}">
    <include name="**/*.jspx"/>
    <include name="**/*.jsp"/>
    <include name="**/*.html"/>                        
    <include name="WEB-INF/*.xml"/>
    <include name="WEB-INF/lib/*.*"/>
    <exclude name="**/web.xml"/>
  </fileset>
</war>
```

Answer (score 1):

Jar up your classes first and tuck that `jar` into the `war` file afterward. Something like this:

```
<target name="war" depends="compile">
    <jar jarfile="${web.dir}/WEB-INF/lib/vms.jar">
      <fileset dir="${classes.dir}">
        <include name="**/*.class"/>
        <exclude name="test/**/*.class"/>
      </fileset>
    </jar>
    <war destfile="${deploy.dir}/vms_war.war" webxml="${web.dir}/WEB-INF/web.xml">
      <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
        <include name="**/*.xml"/>
      </fileset>
      <fileset dir="${web.dir}">
        <include name="**/*.jspx"/>
        <include name="**/*.jsp"/>
        <include name="**/*.html"/>                        
        <include name="WEB-INF/*.xml"/>
        <include name="WEB-INF/lib/*.*"/>
        <exclude name="**/web.xml"/>
      </fileset>
    </war>
  </target>
```